# Whare does app initialization code go in a React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Firstly, I'm new to React so please go easy on me, I have looked for duplicate questions.

I understand React is component based and how to initialize a component but where does code go that runs when the app bootstraps?

For example, I am trying to make a small app which uses PusherJS for websocket based communication. When the app loads I need to connect to a pusher channel via an ajax call and store some data. When Pusher sends events I need to communicate to components lower down (like a MessageList component) that a new message has been received and what the new data is.

For those of you familiar with AngularJS I would have done this in .config() blocks and stored data in a service or in $rootScope but what is "The React Way"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good place to start is wherever you call `ReactDOM.render()` to render your React tree.

Here's pseudo-code for how you might tackle your use case:

```
function render(data) {
  ReactDOM.render(rootElement, <MyApp data={data} />);
}

// connect to socket, then listen for data and re-render whenever data is received
connectSocket()
  .then(socket => {
     render({ status: "connected", data: null });
     socket.on("event", ev => {
       // new data!!
       render({ status: "connected", data: ev.data });
     });
   }, err => render({status "error", data: { error: err } }));

// do an initial render with "connecting" status
render({status: "connecting", data: null });
```

This is a bit of a "toy" example.  For more complicated flows, you'd probably have your socket connection dispatching events to a redux store (or mobX or whatever state solution you are using).

You might also kick off the socket connecting logic in the `componentDidMount` method of your root React component.

Comment: Thank you. So the answer is that the root App component's componentDidMount is the place to put app initialization logic, there is no bootstrapping function as such. The only remaining question is how to send events to deeply nested components, from what I've read I assume that I'm looking at the context API or Redux to do that?

Comment: Yeah you either pass the data all the way down as props or you use a state library like Redux or Mobx. Context is another possibility but I don’t know how well that works

Answer (score 2):

For a very simple application it is possible to utilize component state

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class App extends Component {
    state = { receivedEvent: null };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                (this.state.receivedEvent ? (
                    <div><Event event={this.state.receivedEvent}/></div>
                ) : (
                    <div>display some connecting activity here...</div>
                ))
            </div>
        )
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        connectToSocket().then(receivedEvent => this.setState({receivedEvent}))
    }
}

export default App
```

So, App component can pass event to it's child components as a property. But, it is not a "React" way and it is not recommended to go this way. The "React" way is to use a state container(like Redux). In this way `componentDidMount` shall call reducer and data from state shall be passed to App component with properties.

Comment: @jonhobbs I can comment only my own answers, so do answer your question from another comment here. You do not need to send events to nested components. You bind components to state using `connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ComponentName)`. Notice that here you bind component to reducers as well. So, when some event happens in component, in event handler you need to call reducer. Reducer itself changes state. And this state change cause update of components.